# "too many arguments" with `IF` function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to base on the 3 shifts 00,08,16 use excel auto assign 3 functions A,F,D into each shift and base on the previous auto assigned shift with function to not to duplicate the function again, but after below bold argument, it said too many arguments. Does anyone know other formula to solve? thanks!

=IF(Sheet1!C2="00",IF(B36="00D",INDEX({"00A","00F"},RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),IF(B36="00F", INDEX({"00A","00D"}, RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),"00A")),IF(Sheet1!C2="08",IF(B36="08D",INDEX({"08A","08F"},RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),IF(B36="08F",INDEX({"08A","08D"},RANDBETWEEM(1,2)),"08A"))),**IF(Sheet1!C2="16",IF(B36="16D",INDEX({"16A","16F"},RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),IF(B36="16F",INDEX({"16A","16D"},RANDBETWEEM(1,2)),"16A"))))**

Comment: check your spelling some are written RANDBETWEE`M`. Perhaps using `SWITCH()` or `ifs()`

Answer (score 0):

I like to spread out when getting deep like this:

```
=IF(Sheet1!C2="00",
 IF(B36="00D",INDEX({"00A","00F"},RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),
 IF(B36="00F", INDEX({"00A","00D"}, RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),"00A")),
 IF(Sheet1!C2="08",
IF(B36="08D",INDEX({"08A","08F"},RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),
IF(B36="08F",INDEX({"08A","08D"},RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),"08A")),
IF(Sheet1!C2="16",
IF(B36="16D",INDEX({"16A","16F"},RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),
IF(B36="16F",INDEX({"16A","16D"},RANDBETWEEN(1,2)),"16A")),
"")))
```

Doing that it was easy to see the miss placed `)` after `"08A"))`

But we can simplify the equation a little:

```
=IF(LEFT(B36,2)=C2,C2&IF(OR(RIGHT(B36)={"D","F"}),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"A",IF(RIGHT(B36)="D","F","D")),"A"),C2&"A")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

But I notice that your codes could not be obtained the situation when B36=00A, C36 has opportunity to show 00A

```
=IF(LEFT(B36,2)=C2,C2&IF(OR(RIGHT(B36)={"D","F"}),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"A",IF(RIGHT(B36)="D","F","D")),"A"),C2&"A")
```